# Java SSL two-way handshake - Invalidated cipher suites

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a request from Java to a server, via an SSL protocol. I have both: server pem certificate and client pem certificate. As far as I know I need to generate a p12 file from the server certificate and set it as a keystore as well as import the client certificate to the jks and set it as a truststore. I know both server cert and client cert are valid.

I am able to establish a connection, however my request is not successfull as I am getting a

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

.

I think I am not importing my server_cert.pem to the java key store cacerts correctly.. Anybody can see where I am doing it wrong?

Here is my stacktrace (the part above the "SSL configured" is setting the keystore and the truststore via `apache httpcomponents` and the part below it is my ssl-debug thanks to `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`):

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=sup-48608921133-48515722092-1525185458, O=PTC, C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=LPDA Server Certificate Authority, O=PTC, L=Warsaw, C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x24af
  Valid from Wed Aug 25 10:16:23 CEST 2021 until Mon Aug 24 10:16:23 CEST 2026

...

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 14:00:00 CEST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 13:00:00 CET 2038

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
------------------------- SSL configured -------------------------------------------

...

***
Thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 64
Thread-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 48
Thread-1, RECV TLSv1.1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Thread-1, called closeSocket()
Thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Thread-1, called close()
Thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
myException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: I think you need to do the same test with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and look at the whole lot ... carefully.  The `%% Invalidated:` lines are only saying that that specific suite of cipher algorithms will not be used (because one or other end says "no").  It doesn't actually say what other suites could be used.  In short, there is not enough info here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Note: if this really is a cipher suite incompatibility (and it *could* be ...), you should see the message `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` in the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` log output.

Comment: The client received a TLS alert from the server. It looks like there was already a cipher agreed on (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA). My guess is that the server requires a client certificate which was not provided. But there are too few information in your question, i.e. more of the debug output is needed and not only the parts you yourself considered useful.